# Ansible delegate_to keyword - can I delegate a task to a group defined in an inventory rather than to a specific host?

Tags: ansible

In my playbook I want to run a delegated task on 4 load balancers. Can I just simply use `delegate_to: loadbalancers_group` in my task? Will `delegate_to` accept a group rather than a single host? I am not sure as the Ansible docs say:

> delegate_to - Host to execute task instead of the target (inventory_hostname)

Answer (score 6):

No.  The `delegate_to` option needs to be a host, not a group.

What you can do is loop over the group, e.g.:

```
- file:
    path: touched_file
    state: touch
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['loadbalancers_group'] }}"
```

Answer (score -2):

You could also use when:
Example,

```
- file:
    path: touched_file
    state: touch
  when: inventory_hostname  in groups['loadbalancers_group']
```

Comment: Don't know who downvoted, but it is common courtesy to say WHY one is downvoting an answer.  Here goes.  While what you have may be correct in some situations, it is probably not correct with load balancers.  Typically, the `play_hosts` are the ones managed by the load balancers, and that `file` module is more likely a `lineinfile` that modifies a setting for the `ansible_host` in the load balancer configuration files.  (I found jinja templates easier, but that's just another way to skin the cat.)  So the `play_hosts` are the balanced nodes, but he has to change files on the load balancers.